# Downgrade angular from 4 to 2

Tags: angular

In school i need to write a app with angular 2 not 4 but when i type npm install i have dependency like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "primeng": "^4.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
```

Like i think the @angular/... means version of angular and right now i have 4. I ask my teach to have it in angular 4 but he says "I want only angular 2" :/.
How can i downgrade it to 2?

Comment: Well Angular 4 is actually updated version of Angular 2, so I don't see the reason here... maybe you can talk to you teacher if it's ok to use latest version rather then playing around with deprecated and out-dated things

Comment: Change the version numbers in package.json ...

Comment: Can you get another teacher instead? You can change the version of the dependencies in the package.json file. If you do that, you might need to add other dependencies to make the project work. i.e. angular universal. An example of a package.json file for angular can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/blob/master/package.json, use it as a reference, don't copy and paste it.

Comment: @DawidZbiński I try this but teacher on my university is stubborn :/

Comment: @Henry you meant to change all dependecies with @angular/*

Comment: @PrzemysławZamorski yes, except `@angular/material`. And as Daniel mentioned, you may need to adapt some other versions as well to find a working combination.

Comment: @Henry so i change that version and type npm install and it will install correct version on angular yes ? Because i download some angular2-quickstart and have version of @angular/ 2.* and after type npm install and several hours later when i almost end my app i look into package and see  "@angular/*": "~4.0.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Daniel Ormeño](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5229157/daniel-orme%C3%B1o) stated in the comments

You can manually edit the dependencies like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
```

Note: As these are the old modules, you may encounter warnings like "unmet peer dependency" but you can easily change the version number to the desired one.